# Navigation is working properly on Firefox, Google Chrome v 60, Safari, but not on Google Chrome v 61

Tags: css, google-chrome

Sticky navigation is working properly on many browsers but once I update google chrome it is not working.

How to fix this?

Comment: My site is http://plexus.media/

Comment: Have you checked out the developer tools and console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: The sticky bar works fine in Chrome. You do have some spacing menu items that need to be cleaned up but the sticky nav does work. If you are still getting an error your best bet would be to recreate your issue in a JS Fiddle or Code Pen and post the code here (linking directly to your website is not helpful, especially for future users)